Python: How to convert shapefile of a road network to a Complete Graph network using Networkx
How can I convert a geodataframe of LineStrings to a Complete Graph with NetworkX?
I have a geodataframe of a collection of linestrings that geographically represent a road network (purple). I have 2 points (red and blue) representing A and B. I'd like to find the shortest route between A and B travelling along the road network.

I have converted the geodataframe to a network using momepy library:
road = gpd.read_file(input_road.shp)

#need to explode roads, as is multiline
exploded = road.explode(index_parts=True)

G = momepy.gdf_to_nx(exploded, approach="primal",length='mm_len',multigraph=True)

This successfully converts my road network to a networkx multigraph, whilst preserving distance (mm_len) between points.
Then I add points A and B to the network by getting the closest nodes on the road network to these points:
my_points = gpd.read_file(my_points)

#Firstly, need to convert the coordinates to a tuple of x,y coordinates
for my_point in my_points .geometry.values:
    coords_values = re.findall('[0-9.]+ [0-9.]+', str(my_point ))
    
    #convert list of strings separated by spaces, to a list of coords as list. 
    coords = [sub.split(' ') for sub in coords_values ][0]
    coords_tuple= tuple(map(float, coords ))
    coords_list.append(coords_tuple)

#add this coord tuple as a column in the dataframe
my_points["coords_syntax"] = coords_list

#this dictionary will be used to select the network nodes. The key is the coordinate tuple, and the attribute will be the 'Name' of the point
dict_df_mypoints = home.set_index('coords_syntax')['Name'].to_dict()   

#select the nearest node points on the road network to these coordinate tuples
A = list(G.nodes())

#iterate through dict of coords: my_points
for point in dict_df_mypoints :
    
    
    #get closest node (using KDTree) between point and the array of cords A generated above
    closest_node = A[scipy.spatial.KDTree(A).query(point)[1]]
    
    #make these above closest nodes have attribute my_point, with other attributes (dict_df[point])
    G.nodes[closest_node]['my_point'] = dict_df[point]

So now within all the nodes of my road network, I have 2 representing points A and B respectively. Their node key is the coordinate pair.
However, when I run the shortest_path algorithm between A and B I get this error:
nx.shortest_path(G,source = (455529.02164326626, 206374.9504608615),target = (454340.3426543578, 207204.53480888018))


>>NetworkXNoPath: No path between (455529.02164326626, 206374.9504608615) and (454340.3426543578, 207204.53480888018)

And when I check the edges of these nodes, they are only connected to their 2 neighbours, and no other node:
nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G,source = (455529.02164326626, 206374.9504608615))

 >>{(455529.02164326626, 206374.9504608615): 0,
 >>(455582.6204962559, 206424.4603359318): 1,
 >>(455596.5948359391, 206455.62556823122): 2}

So with my road network, I think I need ALL my nodes to be connected to one another (rather than just to their neighbours) with edges, otherwise the shortest_path won't work. I need to make my network a Complete Graph. However, I have no idea how to do that- it can't be done with Momepy. However I am unsure how to create a NetworkX Graph from scratch whilst preserving the geographical distances between the nodes of the road network - this is what drew me to using Momepy in the first place.

Your title is about how to convert a shapefile, but your question appears to be about how to convert a geodataframe of line strings.  Should the title be updated/corrected?  Or the question content?

see  How to calculate edge length in Networkx, Including length when making a networkx network from a geodataframe or How to convert a shapefile into a graph in which use Dijkstrafor example

To create a Graph using line start and end coordinates for nodes and line lengths as edge weights:
import geopandas as gpd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/NETWORKX/lines_to_graph/roads.shp")

def give_ends(row):
    """A function to return a list of comma separated strings of rounded start and end coordinates,
    Example: ['623373.0,6903082.0', '623386.0,6902378.0']"""
    line_coords = list(row.geometry.coords) #Create a list of all line coordinates
    start = ','.join([str(round(x,0)) for x in line_coords[0]]) #A string, like '623373.0,6903082.0'
    end = ','.join([str(round(x,0)) for x in line_coords[-1]])
    return [start, end]

df[["start","end"]] = df.apply(lambda x: give_ends(x), axis=1, result_type="expand")
df["length"] = df.geometry.length

#Print the top two rows. (Each road have an id column from the shapefile)
# print(df[["id", "start","end","length"]].head(2).to_string(index=False))

#  id              start                end     length
#   0 623373.0,6903082.0 623386.0,6902378.0 707.845229
#   1 623364.0,6903143.0 623373.0,6903082.0  61.635964

#Create the Graph by applying add_edge to each row.
#  Each edge is created with the attribute "length" which is the line length and
#"id" which is a unique id field for each road
G = nx.Graph()
_ = df.apply(lambda x: G.add_edge(x.start, x.end, length=x.length, id=x.id), axis=1)

#If you want shortest path from node to node you can do:
src = "616423.0,6909432.0"
trg = "631116.0,6903670.0"

shortest_path = nx.dijkstra_path(G=G, source=src, 
                        target=trg, weight="length") #A list of nodes from start to end: ['623913.0,6906441.0', '624084.0,6906625.0',..., '627844.0,6909623.0']

shortest_path_length = nx.dijkstra_path_length(G, source=src, target=trg, weight="length")
#print(path_length)
#18123.776975716322
    
shortest_path_edges = list(zip(shortest_path,shortest_path[1:])) #A list of edges from start [('623913.0,6906441.0', '624084.0,6906625.0'), ..., ('627727.0,6909655.0', '627844.0,6909623.0')]

#Plot 
plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(15,10))
pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_size=10, node_color="silver", edge_color="silver") #The complete graph in gray

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=shortest_path_edges, 
                       edge_color='red', width=3) #Shortest path in red

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=[src, trg], node_size=1000, node_color="limegreen", 
                       node_shape="*") #The start and end nodes as green stars


